# Creating data with pre-determined correlations in R

Tags: r, simulation

I am looking to simulate a data set with pre-determined correlations between the variables. The code, below, is where I am at but I want to be able to control the parameters of the features individually.

In short, how do I change the SD, mean and min/max, intervals, skew and kurtosis for each variable individually?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(faux)

cmat <- c(1,   .195,  .346,  .674,  .561,  
         .195,  1,    .479,  .721,  .631,  
         .346, .479,   1,    .154,  .121, 
         .674, .721,  .154,   1,    .241, 
         .561, .631,  .121,  .241,   1)

nps_sales <- round(rnorm_multi(100, 5, 3, .5, cmat, 
                   varnames = c("NPS",
                                "change in NPS",
                                "sales (t0)",
                                "sales (t1)",
                                "sales (t2)")), 0) %>%
    tibble()
```

Comment: Already checked [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/164471), [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38856/how-to-generate-correlated-random-numbers-given-means-variances-and-degree-of), and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30303/how-to-simulate-data-that-satisfy-specific-constraints-such-as-having-specific-m)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified `rnorm_multi(n = 100, vars = 5, mu = 3, sd = .5, cmat = ...)`. `rnorm_multi` will accept vectors of the appropriate length for `mu` and `sd` (e.g. `mu = c(3,3,3,2,2)` and `sd = c(1,0.5,0.5,1,2)`, which will set the means and standard deviations accordingly.

Adjusting the other characteristics (min/max, skew, kurtosis, etc.), will be much more challenging, and may require a question on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com); the reason everyone uses the multivariate normal is that it's easy to specify means, SDs, and correlations, but you can't control the other aspects of the distributions easily.  You can transform the results to achieve some level of skew/kurtosis, but this may not get as much flexibility and control as you want (see e.g. [here](https://psychometroscar.com/2019/10/16/how-to-simulate-correlated-log-normal-random-variables-the-right-way/)).

Comment: Thanks for your input and I thought it would be challenging. I suppose one 'hacky' way of dealing with this is to make the data as is and then rescale each variable individually, not a huge task for such a dataset. The other properties of the distribution are not so important, I just wanted the data to look more 'natural'.

Comment: If you modify individual variables in ways *other* than a simple affine (shift + scale) transformation, you won't preserve the correlation structure.